# Can Matlab hold a strong-name reference to a .NET assembly?

Tags: .net, matlab, strongname

I have a Matlab-generated .exe that needs to reference functionality in a strongly-named, GAC-installed .NET Assembly. From here: [Mathworks help site](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/using-net-from-matlab-an-overview.html) I see the reference would look like this: `function Foo()
NET.addAssembly('MyAssembly');
…
end`
 But I can't find in their docs any description of how to make the reference strong...anyone could produce a strongly-named assembly with the same name and install it in the GAC to spoof the real assembly. Are these references destined to be insecure?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/101936-can-matlab-builder-for-net-create-a-strongly-named-net-assembly

As of MATLAB Builder for .NET 2.1 (R2006b), strongly named .NET assemblies can be created though the Builder does not create them by default. The MWArray.dll, however, is strongly named and can be registered in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

In order to create a strongly named assembly with MATLAB Builder for .NET, you will need to provide a signature file. This file can be generated with the .NET SDK. You can use the DEPLOYTOOL interface to sign the .NET assemby as follows:

1) Open DEPLOYTOOL and creating a MATLAB Builder for .NET project.

2) Add the appropriate files to the project.

3) Undock the DEPLOYTOOL GUI.

4) Go to "Project->Settings" to open the project settings pane.

5) Ensure that you have selected the correct .NET Framework version.

6) Under "Assembly Type", select "shared"

7) For "Encryption Key File", browse for the key file generated by .NET SDK.

8) Build the project.

The .NET assembly is now strongly named and can be registered in the GAC.

Comment: I don't want to strongly-name my Matlab executable. I want it to hold a strong-name reference to an existing strongly-named assembly installed in the GAC.